# Why does this XML file load slowly?

Tags: c#, xml, performance, xhtml

I have some very simple code:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        Console.WriteLine("loading");
        doc.Load(url);
        Console.WriteLine("loaded");

        XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("p");

        foreach(XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.ChildNodes[0].Value);
        }
        return source;
```

I'm working on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_milk_cake) file and it takes two minutes to load. Why does it take so long?  I tried both with fetching and file from the net and loading a local file.

Comment: Uh your link to the file is to a wikipedia article for "hot milk cake"

Comment: You maybe want to check that url again, pretty sure C#'s XML library doesn't load hot milk cakes.

Comment: What's wrong with that? The HTML source is valid XML.

Comment: +1 for Hot Milk Cake, and an interesting question.

Comment: Hot Milk Cake does not pass XML validator test on http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp. One can argue that the .Net doesn't have to load it at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I imagine it's [the DTD of the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd) that's taking so long to load. Given that it defines entities, you shouldn't [disable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215854/prevent-dtd-download-when-parsing-xml), so you're probably better off not going down this path.

Given the inner workings of the wikipedia parser (a right mess), I'd say it's a big leap to assume it's going to produce well-formed XHTML every time.

Use [HTML Agility Pack to parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512562/parsing-html-page-with-htmlagilitypack) (then you can convert to `XmlDocument` a little more easily if required, IIRC).

If you really want to go down the `XmlDocument` route you can keep a local cache of the HTML DTDs. See [this post](http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20090120133541/http://blogs.pingpoet.com/overflow/archive/2005/07/20/6607.aspx), [this post](http://sticklebackplastic.com/post/2007/06/28/How-to-use-XmlResolver-Or-reading-an-xhtml-file-in-net.aspx) and [this post](http://sticklebackplastic.com/post/2007/07/03/XmlResolver-reading-from-resources.aspx) for details.

Comment: +1, beat me to the answer; if you download a copy and remove the DTD it parses right away, but then fails because &reg; is only defined in the DTD.

Comment: The W3C throttles traffic to their DTD files, because they get buried in requests. You could use a custom entityresolver to load local copies of the DTD files.

Answer (score 5):

It is becuase XmlDocument doesn't just load your Xml into a nice class heirarchy it also goes and fetches all of the namespace DTD's defined in the document. Run [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and you will see the calls to fetch

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-symbol.ent
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-special.ent
```

These all took me about 20 seconds to fetch.