# Can I load an XmlDocument without validation?

Tags: c#, xml, validation, linq-to-xml

is it possible to load an XmlDocument like `XDocument.Load(myXmlFile)` without validating the document?
I would like to do the validation myself later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validating XML refers to checking whether the schema maps to the xml data.

XML still has be well-formed in order for it to be loaded into the XmlDocument as it parses the xml into an internal structure.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer. If a schema is referenced, it will try to validate against it. How does one avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [XmlReaderSettings Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) which has properties used to control things like validation. There's no one-size-fits-all answer for turning off validation, as there are different things one may wish to turn off, so browse the object's properties to see what you need. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216747/901812) is an example of using the XmlReaderSettings.