# Fast XML (SVG) Read?

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, xml-parsing

I have an XML (an SVG actually) file, 4000 lines, around 700 individual nodes, with one significant attribute each.

I want to preload the data, and populate actual C# runtime model graph with the data (some string splitting, and property setting).

I did it with `XmlDocument`, the process took **12 sec** (in Unity Editor Play Mode).

I began to implement using `XmlReader`, only to iterate through the file took **6 sec** (without any processing, only `Read`, `MoveToNextAttribute` calls).

**Is there any way to read the file err... ...way faster?**

6-8 sec launch time is something I cannot accept. The whole process should take around... ...half a second at most.

Comment: `XmlReader` should be extremely fast. Can you post the code taking 6 sec? Also 4000 lines is quite small.

Comment: Yap, 4000 lines should not be problem. Seems using DOCTYPE causes the problem. I'm parsing an SVG to obtain tons of polygon data actually.

Comment: I had also the same problem. The first improvement was the same you noticed, i.e. use XmlReader instead of XmlDocument. The second was to use multithreading so as to process the first level nodes in different threads (as many threads as cores on the computer)..

Comment: what is the size in kilobytes of the XML file ?

Comment: Seems it was the `DOCTYPE` definition, I put it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply removed `DOCTYPE` definition from the file itself.

It **boosts 8 times** performance even using original `XmlDocument` implementation.

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"> -->
```

Comment: Maybe I can even go with `XmlDocument` implementation as well? Gonna take a look into.

Comment: I see. That references an external DTD. Most likely that is being downloaded which takes time. There is info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215854/prevent-dtd-download-when-parsing-xml).

Comment: I checked some Xml Files loaded by my applications. They have no DOCTYPE and are loaded in a few seconds for a size of 20 Mb.

Comment: Now it takes `1.06` sec instead of `7.8` all using `XmlDocument`. The document is `334 Kb`. I'm thinking of lazy-parse the leaf nodes, only when they really need.

Comment: Not parsing the actual polygons upfront spares another `0.6` sec. It is actually

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can bypass DTD validation using the settings argument:

```cs
// Files with a <!DOCTYPE ...> get parsed with a super expensive validation; ignore it.
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;
settings.XmlResolver = null;
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath, settings);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);
```